# Does “everything is a file” apply to network printers?

Tags: linux, networking, printing

I asked this question on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393780/does-everything-is-a-file-apply-to-network-printers) and I didn't get any answers or comments, so I thought I'd try here.

If "everything is a file" in Linux, can I access network printers (IPP) like USB printers (`/dev/usb/lp0`)? If so, where?

Comment: "Everything is a file" hasn't been true for *many* years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible, CUPS for example can take the default printer and map it as an /dev/lp device.  I would also look into the lpadmin commands which allow you to map a network printer to a specific device (and hence know where it's mapped).

[Source](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=21525)